# MS Access database monitor query

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the application which use my locally stored access database.

One option is very interesting to me. I would love to know which query is run in background to get data on that option.

Something like

```
Query sniff
Query profiller
Query monitor
```

Is there any way to extract that query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. An Access database is a file, not a server. Any profiling needs to be done by the application executing the query.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8631975/7296893) has some answers on how to get the total time a query is running, but you're likely limited to that. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28370097/7296893) shows you how to get the execution plan for queries, but it requires registry tweaking

Comment: And please note Access is not multithreadable, so you don't rely have anything running in 'background'